# Quick question about storage on android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my first question relating to android development. I would like to know the best way to go about storing an array on an android phone so that even when the app/activity is ended the data remains, I thought about doing it using a SQLite db, but have not been able to find any information about how to keep this database even when the app has ended.

Any advice would be apprectiated, thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods to use in Android to storage data.

- Store data in internal memory (files in internal memory).
- Store data in external memory (files in the sdcard).
- Store data as preferences (SharedPreferences).
- Store data in a SQLLite database.

In my case, I use one method or another depending on the type of data. I only use SharedPreferences for application settings although that is only my rule. To save information in a SQLLite database you only have to insert records, like using any other database. This records will keep saved after your application finish.

You can find more information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: share preferences do not allow arrays only basic types, but i'm sure u can figure out on how to save an array. if you need more elaborated object to be serialized then you can use a file or DB, for filre refferto http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29 for db you can look at DBHelper calsses that ease our job

Comment: So my app is like a shopping list where the user inputs the items they want and then that is saved to later be vied using a list view, each item will have 3 attributes to them so i'm thinking sql datatbase then at runtime turn the strings stored into a custom object to be used later on. My problem is having this database stored even when the app is not in use, so it can retreive that data when it is next opened.

Comment: Sam, the sqllite data is persistent, that is, data is available although you finish your application.